# ASP.NET MVC on Azure Process Large File using Entity Framework - database connection timeout issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, connection-timeout

We have an ASP.NET MVC application that is deployed on Azure. The application allows users to upload large Excel files (around 15 MB = 25K rows).

In the code we are processing the each record in parallel, performing validation on it and if everything looks good we are inserting/updating the records into a SQL Server database in a **single transaction** using Entity Framework. After some time, we are getting SQL Server database connection timeout error.

What's the best way to process this large Excel file in an efficient way without getting timeout error on Azure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't save the file inside the database. The better way is to save it over **file system** or **azure blob storage** and just save the path. Is overhead for the database saving files or binary data inside.

Comment: Thanks Andres for your time and reply! We are not storing whole file. We are processing the file (basically row by row from the excel) and inserting and updating data table into the sql server table using entity framework!

Comment: Right. So, could be somethig about indices or data types in where clause. Also remember that the update action is very expensive for the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use Entity Framework SaveChanges with increased timeout. If you start getting out-of-memory errors then my suggestion is to use [BulkSaveChanges](http://www.zzzprojects.com/demos/dotnet/entity-framework-extensions/bulksavechanges.aspx) from ZZZProjects. With BulkSaveChanges you will upload files faster and avoid timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, I have implemented.

1. Upload large excel file to web server.
2. Parse Excel file
3. Perform validation on the data
4. Create batches of data and send it to the client (Web Browser) or save it in database for further processing.

   public static IEnumerable> Partition(IEnumerable source, int size)
           {
               var partition = new List(size);
               var counter = 0;
               if (source != null)
               {
                   using (var enumerator = source?.GetEnumerator())
                   {
                       while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                       {
                           partition.Add(enumerator.Current);
                           counter++;
                           if (counter % size == 0)
                           {
                               yield return partition.ToList();
                               partition.Clear();
                               counter = 0;
                           }
                       }

   ```
                   if (counter != 0)
                       yield return partition;
               }
           }
       }
   ```
5. Send AJAX request from client to the web server for each batch
6. Update data into the database using entity framework with auto detect changes disabled.

   _context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

Using this approach I was able to upload 5 MB (excel file) around 32K records quickly.

Thank you all for your help!